# Is it possible to have a transparent graphics window in python?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm not sure whether this is possible but can I have a window with animated graphics that is completely transparent so I can see my desktop behind it? Is there something maybe in pygame?

Comment: @user1131308: i dont know exactly how to do this, but have you heard about Jython?

Comment: if it's 100% transparent, do you really need the window?

Comment: technically what I want is a way to overlay an interactive game over my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this with Tkinter and wxPython on this link: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/294803/tkinter-transparent-window

I imagine that you can do this with whatever GUI components Pygame uses, but you need to figure out which ones those are exactly. Or you can use Pygame with Tkinter or wxPython.